# Swift NSLayout uneven alignment

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to mess around with autolayout programmatically in Swift.  However I have one problem.  I want my view1 (red box) to have a the regular spaced alignment with the superview (H:|-[view1]-|)".  This works for the right alignment but not the left.  I want the left side of the view to have the same spacing as the right side.  The view seems to want to align itself horizontally with the button below.  Does anyone know how to fix this or what I am doing wrong? [image]

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "yolo"
        let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var b  = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
        b.frame = CGRectMake(frame.minX + 50, frame.minY + 100, frame.width * 0.8, frame.height * 0.2)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        b.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        b.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        b.setTitle("hello", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        b.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let view1 = UIView()
        view1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let view2 = UIView()
        view2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()


        self.view.addSubview(b)
        self.view.addSubview(view1)
       // dictionary for views
        let viewsDictionary = ["view1":view1,"view2":view2, "b":b]


        let button_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[b(>=200)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let button_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[b(>=200)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        b.addConstraints(button_constraint_H as [AnyObject])
        b.addConstraints(button_constraint_V as [AnyObject])

        //view1
        let view1_constraint_H:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view1(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let view1_constraint_V:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view1(50)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        view1.addConstraints(view1_constraint_H as [AnyObject])
        view1.addConstraints(view1_constraint_V as [AnyObject])


        let view_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[view1]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let view_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-90-[view1]-[b]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
        let view_constraint_H2:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[b]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

        view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H2 as [AnyObject])
        view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V as [AnyObject])
        view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H as [AnyObject])

}
```

Comment: That is really atrocious code. You don't need any of those explicit type declarations or any of those casts. And change `NSLayoutFormatOptions(0)` to `nil` (or to `[]` when you update to Swift 2).

Comment: You should be getting a big error message in the console when you run this code, because your constraints make no sense together. Are you?

Comment: Nope no error or warnings.  Just the picture show above

Comment: Yes, you are. I know for a fact that you are. Do you actually even know how to see the console???

Comment: Your right, I had changed the constraints and ran it again.  With the posted code I get the same error.  Have have messed around changing the constraints but still get the same warning.

Comment: It's not a "warning". Your constraints cannot be obeyed. They make no sense. Did you look at my _answer_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constraints make no sense. You are saying this:

```
"H:[view1(50)]"
"H:|-[view1]-|"
```

So on the one hand you want `view1` to be aligned with the margins of its superview (this is what `-` means), but on the other hand you want `view1` to be exactly 50 points wide (that is what `(50)` means). You can't have both!

Comment: I know your trying to help me and thank you.  However, when I comment out "H:|-[view1]-|", the problem persists.

Comment: No, the problem does not persist. What happens is that you then have _other_ problems. Your constraints _still_ make no sense. For example, on the one hand you say button `b` should be leading-aligned with `view1`, but on the other hand you say it should have its leading edge at its superview's  edge. Try to understand: you are saying a lot of nonsense that makes no sense. You need to decide exactly what you want this layout to be, and ask for that, no less and no more.